# How to define different sources for 2 comboboxes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use comboboxes code taken from [jquery examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox).
This is [modified](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/TFerw/3/) to use remote source.

Now I need to add [second combobox](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/TFerw/5/) with another remote source (countries instead of cities). Of course, I can copy-paste `$.widget("ui.combobox", {` with different source given, but is there any way to simplify the code?

Upd. Looks like I should modify the following code:

```
  $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
      var self = this,
        select = this.element.hide(),
        selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
        value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
      var input = this.input = $( "<input>" )
        .insertAfter( select )
        .val( value )
        .autocomplete({
          delay: 0,
          minLength: 0,

          source: function (request, response) {
              // if id of element is equal to something, then use one url, else
              // use another url
              $.ajax({
                  url: "search/city", type: "GET", dataType: "json",
                  data: { term: request.term },
                  success: function (data) {
                      response($.map(data, function (item) {
                          return {
                              value: item.value,
                              id: item.id
                          }
                      }))
                  }
              })
          },
```

But I don't know how to get element id within `source` function.

Comment: You could change the top of your widget to `$.widget( "ui.combobox", { $this: $(this),
    _create: function() {`. That way you can get the id of the element you attached the widget to with `$this.attr('id');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: To make my post clearer. You just need to use `self.options` to get all the options declared. `this.options` will not work inside `$.ajax({...})` because `this` in that context will return the anonymous function.

If you change the line

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
```

to

```
$.ajax({
     url: self.options.source,
```

, then the ajax call will use whatever source URL you have provided in the "constructor". Then you can simply do:

```
$("#cbCountry").combobox({
    source: someOtherUrl,
   ...
});
```

for a different combobox. See http://jsfiddle.net/k2J5v/1/.

Comment: Surely, I am not so fast as you are ;)

Comment: I didn't mean to sound desperate :). Thanks!